# How can I train AI to learn how to recognize highly impaired speech from a dystonic person?

Tags: deep-learning, speech-recognition

Speech recognition AI generated technology for impaired speech recognition.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done by supervised learning.   Which begins with finding or gathering a corpus of annotated data representative of your problem.  Then training an ML algorithm to minimize its loss on training and test data.

In the case of a task where there are models which do very similar tasks, one may attempt transfer training to minimize the amount of data that needs to be collected.